# Basic Subletting 10.239.142.216/11

Tags: subnet, layer3

First time poster (kindly don't eat me alive)

i was using https://subnetipv4.com/ to acid test my subletting skill i got 9/10 correct

this is the chosen  one that broke my streak

as you can see i missed up by using 128 group size but can anyone explain why they used 64?

[image: losing badly]

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it.

Comment: Hey, that's my Subnetting page ;).  The /11 uses a group size of 32. You can [see the cheat sheet](https://youtu.be/OQ-r_IfeB8c?t=39) to validate that /11 falls under the "32" group size.  Either way, Subnetting questions on this site are typically closed and users are directed [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106).

Comment: Thank you and Eddie for your valuable contribution , i see the error of my way , my train  thought was like this

00000110.1000000  = 10.128
i forget that 255.0.0.0 != /10 :( sorry

=~= when ip6v is coming :(

btw i don't know how to reply :( to lazy to google it